# Sorting ArrayList according to 2 attributes

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I want to sort my ArrayList on the base of 2 attributes. First on the base of ID and then on the base of some score. Each entry has some score. Here is code.

```
        public class OutputSentence {
        int tokenId;
        double similarityScore;
        String title;
        String quantity;
        String unit;

        public OutputSentence(int tokenId,double similarityScore,String title,String quantity,String unit) 
        {
            this.tokenId = tokenId;
            this.similarityScore = similarityScore;
            this.title = title;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.unit = unit;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ("Token_ID: "+this.tokenId + " Score: "+this.similarityScore + " Title: "+ this.title + " Quantity: "+this.quantity+
                    " Unit: "+this.unit);
        }

        public int getTokenId()
        {
            return this.tokenId;
        }
        public double getSimilarityScore()
        {
            return this.similarityScore;
        }

    }
class MyComparator implements Comparator<OutputSentence>{
    public int compare(OutputSentence s1, OutputSentence s2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = Integer.valueOf(s1.getTokenId()).compareTo(s2.getTokenId());


        return result;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<OutputSentence> finalOutput = new ArrayList<OutputSentence>();
        finalOutput.add(new OutputSentence(0, 0.1, "Hello1", "Half", "box"));
        finalOutput.add(new OutputSentence(5, 0.7, "Coffee", "Half", "cup"));
        finalOutput.add(new OutputSentence(0, 0.4, "Apple juice", "Glass", "one"));
        Collections.sort(finalOutput, new MyComparator());
        for(OutputSentence out:finalOutput)
        System.out.println(out);
}
```

This is giving me following results.
Token_ID: 0 Score: 0.1 Title: Hello1 Quantity: Half Unit: box
Token_ID: 0 Score: 0.4 Title: Apple juice Quantity: Glass Unit: one
Token_ID: 5 Score: 0.7 Title: Coffee Quantity: Half Unit: cup

But I need these results.
Token_ID: 0 Score: 0.4 Title: Apple juice Quantity: Glass Unit: one
Token_ID: 0 Score: 0.1 Title: Hello1 Quantity: Half Unit: box
Token_ID: 5 Score: 0.7 Title: Coffee Quantity: Half Unit: cup

First Sort on the base of token_ID and then sort on the base of Similarity Score. How can I write my comparator to give me required results? OR I have to write a new Comparator?
I will be thankful to you.

Comment: By "first sort on X then on Y" you mean: if the Xs are equal, then compare the Ys?

Comment: since this looks like an homework, you have to do it for yourself. A hint: in your compare: if tokenids are equal then return the value of comparing the similarity score, otherwise return the comaprison of tonkenIds

Comment: @AlexWien It is not a homework.

Comment: @dotvav Yes you got it right. I solve it and posted my answer.

Comment: @AlexWien I posted my answer.

Comment: your answer is wrong

Comment: @AlexWien Yes there was a mistake. I correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a new Comparator. It is working fine. Here it is.

```
class MyComparator2 implements Comparator<OutputSentence>{
    public int compare(OutputSentence s1, OutputSentence s2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = Integer.valueOf(s1.getTokenId()).compareTo(s2.getTokenId());
        if(result==0)
        {
            int result1 = Double.valueOf(s2.getSimilarityScore()).compareTo(s1.getSimilarityScore());
            return result1;
        }
        else
            return result;
    }
}
```

Now I am getting.
Token_ID: 0 Score: 0.4 Title: Apple juice Quantity: Glass Unit: one
Token_ID: 0 Score: 0.1 Title: Hello1 Quantity: Half Unit: box
Token_ID: 5 Score: 0.7 Title: Coffee Quantity: Half Unit: cup

Comment: return 2 is wrong, it must be "return result" instead

Comment: As I my solution shows, you should return result if result != 0 else you loose the information when result == -1

Answer (score 2):

As `SimilarityScore` is ordered from higher it is neccesary to invert compareTo result:

`int result = Integer.valueOf(s1.getTokenId()).compareTo(s2.getTokenId());
if(result == 0){
    result = s2.getSimilarityScore().compareTo(s1.getSimilarityScore());`

Comment: why * -1? who want to invert the sort order ?

Comment: He wants 0 - 0.4 be first than 0 - 0.1. So first value is ordered from lower to higher and second one is ordered from higher to lower

Comment: In order to invert the sort it is easier to just switch s1 and s2 in my opinion, but you are right he wants to sort it descending.

Comment: yes only switching is the correct solution. because *-1 does not work for values like INFINITY

Comment: i removed my donwvote , but the code is atill not perfect, swicthing s1,s2 is better than * -1.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is when the IDs are the same to sort it by the score. You can add this 'if'-clause to check if the values are the same and then return the result of the compared scores, as I did in the code below:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<OutputSentence>{
    public int compare(OutputSentence s1, OutputSentence s2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = Integer.valueOf(s1.getTokenId()).compareTo(s2.getTokenId());

    if(result == 0){
        //if you want to sort it by score descending, just switch s1 and s2
        result = Double.valueOf(s1.getSimilarityScore()).compareTo(s2.getSimilarityScore());   
    }

    return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your compare method like this and use a list of comprators according to your need :-

```
@Override
    public int compare(OutputSentence  s1, OutputSentence s2) {
        for (Comparator<OutputSentence> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(s1, s2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting and elegant for solutions with more than two attributes to sort

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<OutputSentence>{
    public int compare(OutputSentence s1, OutputSentence s2) {
        int result = Integer.valueOf(s1.getTokenId()).compareTo(s2.getTokenId());
        if(result == 0){
             return Double.valueOf(s1.getSimilarityScore()).compareTo(s2.getSimilarityScore());
        } else {
             return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache Commons CompareToBuilder, see an example:-

```
public class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
            return new CompareToBuilder()
                    .append(o1.getJobTitle(), o2.getJobTitle())
                    .append(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge())
                    .append(o1.getSalary(), o2.getSalary()).toComparison();
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(listEmployees, new EmployeeComparator());
```